# id_dsa authentication works in one direction but not the other

Tags: ssh, authentication, scp

I have two laptops running 18.04.    Both have identical .ssh folders.    I can copy from the new one to the old one using `scp` with id_dsa authentication, but in the other direction this mode of authentication fails using exactly the same command.      Here's the relevant lines from runing `scp -v`.    In one direction I see:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/simon/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

In the other I see:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/simon/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

Could anybody please suggest where I might look for something different on the two machines?     I presume that I must have made a system change on the old machine that I haven't replicated on the new one.

The contents of my `.ssh` folder on each machine are identical:

```
simon@5540:~/.ssh>ls -al
total 32
drwx------  2 simon simon 4096 Jan 16 11:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 28 simon simon 4096 Jan 16 11:32 ../
-rw-------  1 simon simon 1202 Jan 16 11:30 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 simon simon  668 Jan 16 11:30 id_dsa
-rw-------  1 simon simon 1675 Jan 16 11:30 identity
-rw-------  1 simon simon 1679 Jan 16 11:30 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 simon simon  391 Jan 16 11:30 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 simon simon  666 Jan 16 11:30 known_hosts
```

Comment: Probably this is permission issue. Please edit the question and post the output of `ls -la ~/.ssh`.

Comment: Hello, Leo Simon - what are the permissions of the directory `/.ssh` itself, it must be `700`, also I think you should try to set `600` for all files in the directory (`find ~/.ssh -type f -exec chmod 600 {} +`). Currently the file `authorized_keys` has `644` that normally shouldn't be accepted by the ssh service, see this manual as reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was that I was missing a line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

On my old machine I had the line

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

When I added this line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the new machine, and restarted the `sshd` server application as instructed in the link that @pa4080 provided, then authentication worked as expected.